# Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream - org.springframework.cloud.skipper.SkipperException: Can not find a package named

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

While deploying Streams in SCDF 2.9.2 with skipper 2.8.2, I observed frequent scenarios, wherein if a stream deployment fails for some reason, I cannot destroy the stream definition or re-deploy the stream definition. It fails with the following error:-
`org.springframework.cloud.skipper.SkipperException: Can not find a package named - StreamName`
I have to re-deploy using a different name. This is not ideal at all for Production scenarios. Is there a way around to force delete? I am using Cloud Foundry as the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no capability for forced delete. Linking this report to the existing Dataflow [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5373#issuecomment-1594906473).

If you could please provide the sections of the Dataflow and Skipper logs around the time of the failures - that would be much appreciated.